# Can't kill robocopy subprocess from python

Tags: python, subprocess, robocopy

In my project on windows, I would like to start the mirroring of two directories.

I know that I can use python watchdog to do that, but I though that using robocopy would be easier and faster.

To simplify the situation,  let's assume I have a GUI with two buttons: start and stop mirroring.

Here below is a snippet with the relevant code:

```
class MirrorDemon(Thread):
    
    def __init__(self, src, dest) :
        self.threading_flag = Event()
        self.src = src
        self.dest = dest
        self.opt = ' /MIR /MON:1 /MOT:1'
        self.mirror = None
        Thread.__init__(self)
        
        
    def run(self):
        
        command = 'robocopy {} {} {}'.format(str(self.src),str(self.dest), self.opt)
        
        self.p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=True)
        print(command)
        print('start robocopy with PID {}'.format(self.p.pid))

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
    def stop_demon(self):
        self.mirror.threading_flag.set()
        self.mirror.p.kill()      
        self.mirror.join()
        print('stop demon')
    
    def start_demon(self):
        self.mirror = MirrorDemon(Path('./src'), Path('./dest'))
        self.mirror.setDaemon(True)
        self.mirror.start()
        print('start demon')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

When you click on the start button, you get a PID print out on the console and if I check this PID in the tasklist it corresponds to 'cmd.exe' process and the robocopy starts its job.

When you click on stop, the cmd.exe process corresponding to the PID disappers, but the background robocopy continues!!

I have tried several variations, but no luck.

Do you have some advises? Do you know if somebody has found a solution? Or maybe implemented a mirroring watchdog?

thanks

## Update

Following the the suggestion of @Ulrich, setting shell=False is actually doing the trick and killing the robocopy process.

Thanks!

Comment: If you kill the shell, it doesn't necessarily kill the process started from that shell. In any case, don't run an intermediate shell, run robocopy in a direct subprocess.

Comment: you mean to set shell=False?

Comment: Since you ended up answering your own question and user @ulricheckhardt didn't post the suggestion as an answer, you should do 1 of 2 things: either close the question, since it no longer requires an answer, or write a brief answer yourself and accept it, so it appears as answered when people find it. (or you can wait for someone else to do it, to farm some karma, but that's not really what we're here for)

Comment: @Grismar, thanks for your suggestions. I edited already my question adding the answer from Ulrich. At the moment, I can't answer my question, nor close it. I can only delete it, but this is probably not what you were suggesting. As soon as I can reply, I will add the answer

Comment: Ah, I see - in that case, I've just put the info in an answer for you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing this:

```
self.p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=True)
```

To this:

```
self.p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=False)
```

... you're ensuring that the process will be started directly from the current process, without starting a new shell process to start it in.

The PID you were getting back was for the shell process, and you can kill the shell without killing processes launched from that shell. By not starting it in a new shell, the PID you're getting back is the PID of the actual process and you'll be able to kill it as expected.

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) states: "The only time you need to specify `shell=True` on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch file or console-based executable."

Comment: Just one comment: `command.split()` should be avoided. You're assembling a command line just to split it up again. Not only is this unnecessary, it will even fail if one of the paths contains spaces. Use a `list` and put into it exactly what you want to have in `sys.argv` on the other side.